# powershell, excel,autofilter , not equal

Tags: excel, powershell, autofilter

How do I exclude only 1 item out of say 7? instead of choosing 6 of them.. The above "clears" the column..
Looking at the Custom Auto Filter from Excel....

- Item1 = X
- Item2 = X
- Item3 = X
- Item4 = X
- Item5 = X
- Item6 =
- Item7 = X

Where the x represents the check box in Excel.

How do i automate this, "reverse" choice, or NOT Equal Too....
Looking at the Custom AutoFilter, how do I automate,

- does not equal  {Item6}

One last item, this must be in Powershell code, NOT VB, or C#, or Excel Macro....

$$**Jiw**@@

Comment: What have you tried? You don't show any code, or errors, or anything. You reference 'The above' but there is nothing above to reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = @('item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6','item7')

$list | Where-Object {$_ -ne 'item6'} | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
```

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but the code above takes as array for example, excludes 'item6' using the -ne (not equal to) switch, and then writes each item not excluded to the console.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear..However, the above answer is not what i am looking for.. I am not looking to omit part of an array, but only choose one in a list to omit. so I am working on data mining on a spreadsheet and have a list of items in one column. Instead of to only deselect one item in a column so if any were added to the column they would also be included. I Hope this is clearer

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to clear a column of your choosing, the quickest and easiest way is to use the following code:

`worksheet.Cells.Item(X, Y).EntireColumn.ClearContents`

So you create your workbook instance and then create a worksheet instance. Then pick the column using the X and Y values (eg: "A1" = (1, 1)).

You are not very clear on what you are looking for but from what I read, this is my solution to what you have described.